# Angular conditional email validation

Tags: angularjs, email-validation

How can I conditionally use angular's email validation based on the presence of another scope variable? I looked through the documentation but the only way I can find to trigger email validation is to use `input type="email"`, which in this case I cannot use due to the dependence of another directive on `type="text"`.

Ideally I'd either like to assign ng-match="email" based on the value of another scope variable, or just validate the email programatically on submission. In theory I could just a separate email validation regex but if possible I'd like to use Angular's validation since I use that everywhere else.

Thanks

--
Edit: To clarify, I specifically would like to use angular's native email validation in whatever solution I end up using.

Comment: Just write a custom directive for that

Comment: Yeah I know I can do that, but how can I use angular's native email validation in that directive, if I go that route?

Comment: You can set a higher **priority** for your directive than the email one.(assuming you are treating your process in the linking function of your directive). So that the email validation would occur BEFORE the process of your custom directive.

Comment: Ok, but I only want the email validation to occur some of the time. If it occurs before my directive won't it execute all the time? Or, do you mean to use the second directive to override the $invalid setting the field would get if it's not an email?

Comment: Why do you want a non-idempotent behavior? Of course it will be execute all the time.

Comment: If you want a behavior strictly based on your proper conditions, make your input as `type="text"`, and just implement a regexp in your directive to mimic the email's one.

Comment: I just don't feel right about using two different versions of email validation if I don't have to. But from the answers it seems like there's no way of using Angular's native email validation anywhere else outside of `input type="email"`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ng-required` and `ng-pattern` on the email input field.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="email" ng-required="emailRequired" ng-pattern="emailPattern" />
```

And then define `emailPattern` as function on the `$scope` of your controller.

```
$scope.emailPattern = (function() {
var regexp = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return {
    test: function(value) {
        if( $scope.emailRequired === false ) return true;
        else return regexp.test(value);
    }
};
```

})();

The following fiddle implements what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/9SSE4/

Comment: Right, but no way to use angular's regex without copying it explicitly?

Comment: No, because angular's regex email validation works only with input of type="email".

Comment: You can try by yourself directly on the angular's documentation example. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/5uW2U/

Comment: Ok but my question was "How can I conditionally use angular's email validation", not a different email validation. But from what you're saying it looks like I can't use it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change the type of the input? If the input should be validated as an email then set its type to an email, else set it to text.

```
<input type="{{vm.type}}" ng-model="vm.text" />
<select ng-model="vm.type">
  <option>text</option>
  <option>email</option>
```

[Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DqforCRipfKnjMlgoawh?p=preview)