# How to trigger Form Validators in Angular2

Tags: forms, validation, angular

In angular2 I want to trigger Validators for some controls when a another control is changed. Is there some way that I can just tell the form to re-validate?  Better still, can I request validation of specific fields?

Example:
Given Checkbox X and input P.
Input P has a validator that behaves differently based on the model value of X.
When X is checked/unchecked I need to invoke the validator on P. The Validator on P will look at the model to determine the state of X and will validate P accordingly.

Here's some code:

```
constructor(builder: FormBuilder) {
    this.formData = { num: '', checkbox: false };

    this.formGp = builder.group({
        numberFld: [this.formData.num, myValidators.numericRange],
        checkboxFld: [this.formData.checkbox],
    });
}

this.formGp.controls['checkboxFld'].valueChanges.observer({
    next: (value) => {
        // I want to be able to do something like the following line:
        this.formGp.controls['numberFld'].validator(this.formGp.controls['numberFld']);
    }
});
```

Anybody have a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Are you just trying to enable/disable the validation based on the value of X?  What sort of validators are you using?  You can cause validators to execute based on a condition in your scope, but I'm not sure if that approach will work for you.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370006/angular-conditional-email-validation

Comment: @stephen.vakil - I'm using angular2.

Comment: @Bonneville could you please explain how you are passing the checkbox state to the validator function?

Answer (score 108):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer, so here is my suggestions:

Have a look at this: [Angular 2 - AbstractControl](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L413)

I think what you could do is following:

```
this.formGp.controls['checkboxFld'].valueChanges.observer({
    next: (value) => {
       this.formGp.controls['numberFld'].updateValueAndValidity();
    }
});
```

This should trigger and run the validators. Furthermore the state gets updated as well. Now you should be able to consult the checkbox value within your validator logic.

[Validaton-Guide](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

[FormControl Documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl)

Comment: Thanks @Nightking for the suggestion, I'll try it out. Note that your link isn't working.

Comment: @Bonneville Thanks for the information. They extracted the form code to the common namespace. Things changing a bit to fast :). I've updated the link to the source.

Comment: I finally got around to using this piece of code and it seems to be working for me. Thanks!  BTW, there is a typo in your code: the letter 'e' is missing in the updateValueAndValidity() function. Your code has updat instead of update. Cheers, this was a big help!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Great that this works for you! Could you upvote or mark my answer? For my reputation :).

Comment: Link is broken; may be updated to https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L413 although not quite the same. Could also link to Angular docs

Comment: Life saver!! The use case that I was stuck was when the user submits a form without touching a single form control. The form is invalid but the controls where not showing any error message

Comment: @pravin thank you. We had the same use case over here. I have to mention that maybe you have to go through all your controls on a FormGroup and call "updateValueAndValidity()", because this function only checks it's own validity and the one of it's parent. So if you call it on a FormGroup it just bubbles upwards and doesn't check other controls. Thought this could may be helpful :)

Comment: Works very well, thx !

Answer (score 61):

with my ControlGroup I do this because I have errors divs checking if touched

```
for (var i in this.form.controls) {
  this.form.controls[i].markAsTouched();
}
```

(this.form is my ControlGroup)

Comment: this is actually the right answer. If you want single input this.form.controls['name'].markAsTouched();

Answer (score 32):

With the help of this blog

[blog link](https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-reactive-forms-trigger-validation-on-submit/)

I have came across a solution with the combine of Nightking answer

```
Object.keys(this.orderForm.controls).forEach(field => {
       const control = this.orderForm.get(field);
       control.updateValueAndValidity();

});
```

> **this.orderForm** is the form group

Answer (score 32):

This did the trick for me

```
this.myForm.markAllAsTouched();
```

Comment: The problem with marking as touched is that if you are tracking changes, like to tell them there are unsaved changes upon leaving, then this will trigger that logic

Comment: @stevec I didn't have understand your comment! Could you leave a demo here?! 
I'm using of *markAllAsTouched* method, whereas I *updateValueAndValidity* method didn't work for me to re-validate my inputs!

Answer (score 6):

There are more elegant ways of modeling this behavior - for example, putting your state into a ReplaySubject and observing that, and then using async validators observing the state - but the pseudo-coded approach below should work. You simply observe the value changes in the checkbox, update the model as appropriate, then force a re-validation of the numberFld with the updateValueAndValidity cal.

```
constructor(builder: FormBuilder) {
  this.formData = { num: '', checkbox: false };
  const numberFld = builder.control(this.formData.num, myValidators.numericRange);

  const checkbox = builder.control(this.formData.checkbox);
  checkbox.valueChanges.map(mapToBoolean).subscribe((bool) => {
    this.formData.checked = bool;
    numberFld.updateValueAndValidity(); //triggers numberFld validation
  });

  this.formGp = builder.group({
      numberFld: numberFld,
      checkboxFld: checkbox
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can trigger validation in this way:

```
this.myform.get('myfield').updateValueAndValidity();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another similar way that also uses markAsDirty and updateValueAndValidity, particularly good if you use angular material where markAsTouched is not enough.

```
export function forceValidation(form: AbstractControl) {
  if (form instanceof FormGroup || form instanceof FormArray) {
    for (const inner in form.controls) {
      const control = form.get(inner);
      control && forceValidation(control);
    }
  } else {
    form.markAsDirty();
    form.markAsTouched();
    form.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static minMaxRange(min: number, max: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        if (Validators.min(min)(control)) { // if min not valid
            return Validators.min(min)(control);
        } else {
            return Validators.max(max)(control);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, we need to call the [markAsTouched()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAsTouched) method over [`FormControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl).
But what if the control itself is actually [`FormGroup`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)?

Here is the code handling all possible nestings:

```js
triggerFormValidation(formGroup: any = this.myCreateForm): void {
    for (const key in formGroup.controls) {
        const control = formGroup.controls[key];

        if (!control.controls) { // FormControl case
            control.markAsTouched(); // trigger changes check
        } else { 
            this.triggerFormValidation(control); // FormGroup case
        }
    }
}
```