# General: asynchonious validation in angular2

Tags: validation, asynchronous, angular

Since couple evening I've played with form validation in augular2.

All basic cases were easy to implement and they works fine but I stick with asynchronous validation. I have created a very tiny example http://plnkr.co/edit/Xo8xwJjhlHkXrunzS8ZE and it didn't work.

According to test "should fire an event after the status has been updated to pending" from model_spec.ts Registration via creation of control group suppose to work in a way

```
builder.group({login: ["",Validators.required,validationFuctionWhichReturnsPromise]
```

I spent a full evening to discovered that this code has been released in alfa-46 (and I used alfa-45) and after update depencies the async validation started to work. The feature is  very fresh and is not fully documented but

(for those who haven't tried it yet) Basically async validator is a function which have a Control argument and return a promise which validation result. There are two ways to register a validator. 1) the one which I used in my example and 2)  as a directive which Provide validators via NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS (See UniqLoginValidator and NgFormControl to see how it work). You can compose more than one validator (not tested yet but functions to do this are in code, see https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/cf449dd).

But when I finally reach to up and running validators a new problem arrived. Async validator is perfect to used it in server side validation. But the validation is invoked after each change of model.fe after each keyup. So if we will send request to a server after each key up, it won't be too efficient way ;) I checked how it is done in angular 1 and they is a possibility to debounce validation events.

My questions are:

1. How to implement throttle or debounce with async validators? I saw some ideas but none of them were fine (mostly because they need to change angular code itself). Is there any valid way to do this without waiting for new angular release ?

I was thinking about to warping a validator function with debounce (from underscorejs) but it will not work because angular expects to get a valid promise every time.

My second though was that if all event use RxJs under the hood then maybe I can apply debounce on stream of event which is responsible for validation. In model.ts the promise returned from validator is change to observable and a new subscribed is added. We don't have any access to obs(Observable) to apply debounce there.

2. Is there any way or id to change,easy extend a control over the form validation ?

I spotted a close related problem in [How to trigger Form Validators in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260082/how-to-trigger-form-validators-in-angular2)

PS there is other issue related to async validators and it is still open https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1068

Comment: Regarding the first question I haven't used async validators, so this is pure guessing : have you tried with `Observable.debounce()/throttle().toPromise()`?

Comment: No I haven't, I will check it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260082/how-to-trigger-form-validators-in-angular2#comment56174652_33377290

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38022310/199260, very clear and easy to implement

Answer (score 9):

Here is a helper class that you can use to debounce all your async validators:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import {Control} from 'angular2/common';

export class AsyncValidator {
_validate;

constructor(validator: (control: Control) => any, debounceTime = 1000) {
    let source: any = new Observable((observer: Observer<Control>) => {
        this._validate = (control) => observer.next(control);
    });

    source.debounceTime(debounceTime)
        .distinctUntilChanged(null, (x) => x.control.value)
        .map(x => { return { promise: validator(x.control), resolver: x.promiseResolver }; })
        .subscribe(
            (x) => x.promise.then(resultValue => x.resolver(resultValue),
            (e) => { console.log('async validator error: %s', e); }));
}

private _getValidator() {
    return (control) => {
        let promiseResolver;
        let p = new Promise((resolve) => {
            promiseResolver = resolve;
        });
        this._validate({ control: control, promiseResolver: promiseResolver });
        return p;
    };
}

static debounce(validator: (control: Control) => any, debounceTime = 400) {
    var asyncValidator = new this(validator, debounceTime);
    return asyncValidator._getValidator();
}
}
```

Then all you have to do where use async validators is just wrap your validator with this call and write your validator the same as you would normally:

```
AsyncValidator.debounce(control => this.asyncValidator(control));
```

Here is an example usage:

```
export class AppComponent {
form: ControlGroup;

constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    var validator = AsyncValidator.debounce(control => this.asyncValidator(control));

    this.form = _formBuilder.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required, validator],
    });
}

asyncValidator(control): any {
    let p = new Promise(resolve => {
        // get from server information need to validate control

        if (control.value === 'valid value') {
            resolve(null);
        } else {

            resolve({
                asyncValidator: {
                    valid: false
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return p;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an awesome issue on angular site that deals with the problem of both debouncing and switchMapping the validation:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6895

This is mine working solution (but all the credit goes to guys from thread)

```
class AsyncValidator{
  private validatorInput: Subject<string>;
  private validatorChain: Observable<any>;
  constructor(service: ManageUsersService) {
    this.validatorInput = new Subject();
    this.validatorChain = this.validatorInput
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(value => service.findUsersByName(value)
                                 .map(() => ({error: 'Error'})) //example of failed validation
                                 .catch(() => Observable.of(null))) //example of successful validation
      .do(v => console.log('mapped', v))
      .share()
      .take(1);
  }

  validate = (control: AbstractControl) => {
    // An immediate timeout is set because the next has to occur after the 
    // validator chain is subscribed to.
    setTimeout(() => this.validatorInput.next(control.value), 0);
    return this.validatorChain;
}
```

You use it like this:

```
this.createUserForm = fb.group({
        login: [ null, 
                 Validators.required, 
                 new AsyncValidator(userService).validate
               ],
      });
    }
```

Comment: @charlie_pl You can use a ReplaySubject instead of a Subject to ensure the value is present when the validator is subscribed to. This would be much more reliable.