# Async form validation with debounce?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am wondering how can I implement the debounce time on my async validator.

I have the following:

```
...
password: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.passwordValid])]
...
```

Where:

```
passwordValid(control:Control):{ [key: string]: any; } {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this._http.post('/passwordCheck', control.value)
            .subscribe(
                success=>{
                    resolve(null);
                },
                error=>{
                    resolve({passwordValid: false})
                }
            )
    })
}
```

However now, the validation is triggered at each keystroke. I need to add debounce functionality. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible out of the box since the validator is directly triggered when the `input` event is used to trigger updates. See this line in the source code:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L23

If you want to leverage a debounce time at this level, you need to get an observable directly linked with the `input` event of the corresponding DOM element. This issue in Github could give you the context:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4062

In your case, a workaround would be to implement a custom value accessor leveraging the `fromEvent` method of observable.

Here is a sample:

```
const DEBOUNCE_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => DebounceInputControlValueAccessor), multi: true});

@Directive({
  selector: '[debounceTime]',
  //host: {'(change)': 'doOnChange($event.target)', '(blur)': 'onTouched()'},
  providers: [DEBOUNCE_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class DebounceInputControlValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};
  @Input()
  debounceTime:number;

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _renderer:Renderer) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    Observable.fromEvent(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .debounceTime(this.debounceTime)
      .subscribe((event) => {
        this.onChange(event.target.value);
      });
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    var normalizedValue = isBlank(value) ? '' : value;
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', normalizedValue);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: () => any): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => any): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
function validator(ctrl) {
  console.log('validator called');
  console.log(ctrl);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app'
  template: `
    <form>
      <div>
        <input [debounceTime]="2000" [ngFormControl]="ctrl"/>
      </div>
      value : {{ctrl.value}}
    </form>
  `,
  directives: [ DebounceInputControlValueAccessor ]
})
export class App {
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.ctrl = new Control('', validator);
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/u23ZgaXjAvzFpeScZbpJ?p=preview.

Answer (score 1):

Another much simpler implementation could be as described in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38022310/4655056

You could also update that implementation to unsubscribe an active subscription before new subscription/request is created.

This is my async validator example:

```
private _uniqueUsernameValidator(control: FormControl): Promise<any> {
if (this._uniqueUsernameSubscription) {
  this._uniqueUsernameSubscription.unsubscribe();
}

if (this._uniqueUsernameTimeout) {
  clearTimeout(this._uniqueUsernameTimeout);
}

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this._uniqueUsernameTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    this._uniqueUsernameSubscription = this._SecurityResource.getUsernameExists(control.value).subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp === false) {
        resolve(null);
      } else {
        resolve({customMessage: {message: 'This username is already taken'}});
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

}