# Angular2 control validation when a user finishes typing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to perform validation with tthe server to check if an email is already registered but only on blur not on value change

I have an option to add multiple controls and this is how ive organized my form

```
    ngOninit(){
      this.userForm = this._formBuilder.group({
       others: this._formBuilder.array([])  //multiple
      });

      this.onAddControl();  //allows adding multiple items
    }



    onAddControl(){

        return this._formBuilder.group({
         email: ['' [this._validateServ.emailDoesntExistsValidator.bind(this._validateServ)]
         ],

       });
   }
 }
```

Now on the `_validateServ`

```
emailDoesntExistsValidator(control) {
  if (control.value != undefined) {
    if(!this.emailValueValidator(control)){
       return this._authService.checkExists("email",control.value)  //http request
        .map(response => {
          if (response) {
            return {'emailTaken': true};
         }
      });
    }

  }
}
```

I would like the email validation to run on blur since it is performing a http request so that i can show the waiting as http request is being performed
The above works but works on each keypress but not on blur event

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that you can *delay control validation*.

But there are two things you could delay:

- **The HTTP request.** The `debounceTime()` operator lets you wait for n milliseconds after the user has finished typing to execute the request. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38802283).
- **The displaying of the error.** Even though the validity of the field is calculated as the user types, you can still wait for blur to *show* the error. Set a flag to true when the field blurs: `<input (blur)="displayError=true">`. Then use that flag to display the error: `<div *ngIf="error && displayError">Error message</div>`.