# debounce() waits and then hits server for each keystroke

Tags: angular, observable

I'm writing an asynchronous validator that checks uniqueness of `title`. If titles match then the backend throws and error, this should fire the validation.

component.ts:

```
constructor(
       public http:Http,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
            this.form = formBuilder.group({
                title: ['', Validators.required, uniqueTitle.bind(this)]
            });
}
```

validator.ts

```
export function uniqueTitle(control: FormControl) : Observable<any> {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  return new Observable((obs: any) => {
    control
        .valueChanges
        .debounceTime(4000)
        .flatMap(value => this.http.get('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/academic_terms/show_by_title?title=' + control.value, {headers}))
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                obs.next(null);
                obs.complete();
            },
            error => {
                let message = error.json().errors;
                let reason;

                if (message === 'Title Taken') {
                    reason = 'validateTitle';
                }
                obs.next({ [reason]: 'Title has already been taken' });
                obs.complete();
            }
        );
  });
}
```

This works fine, but if I quickly type any title with say 10 chars then the debounce will wait (4 seconds in this case ... for testing) and it will then hit the server 10 times.

- A
- AB
- ABC
- etc

Am I missing something here?  I read that it might have something to do with the fact that I'm not returning an observable but I can't make sense of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919011/how-to-add-debounce-time-to-an-async-validator-in-angular-2 you'll need to implement a workaround

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @silentsod.  There seems to be issues with debouncing Observables with asynchronous validators.  From this I reverted to using a Promise with the setTimeout() as suggested in the post above by izupet and now only one call is made.

Comment: No problem, I'll flag this as a dupe so if someone comes across this question they'll find the other I linked.