# Angular FormControl async validation, benefit from Observable

Tags: angular, validation, rxjs, observable

I am playing with Angular form validation to implement a custom async validator which works well with Promises, but.. I would like to avoid Promises and use Observable to benefit from its useful methods and make it simpler.

I have done the following thing which is working well:

```
class OrderFormComponent{

    issueSubject: FormControl;

    static checkAsyncValue(val: string){
        return new Observable(observer => {
              setTimeout(() => { //Timeout just to simulate an async call
                  if( val.substr(0,2) != "#SUBJECT_" ) {
                    observer.next(false);
                  } else {
                    observer.next(true);
                  }
                  observer.complete();
              }, 500);
        });
    }


    constructor(fb: FormBuilder){

        this.issueSubject = fb.control('', [Validators.required], []]);
        const issueSubject = this.issueSubject;
        let checkValue = function(value){
            OrderFormComponent.checkAsyncValue(value).subscribe((result) => {
                  if (result !== true) {
                    issueSubject.setErrors({
                      notunique: true
                    });
                  }
            });
        }
        issueSubject.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).distinctUntilChanged().subscribe(value => {
            checkValue(value);
        });
        this.issueSubject.setValue('Test Bad Subject');

        this.issueForm = fb.group({
            subject:   this.issueSubject
        });     
    }

}
```

**But**, what I would like to do is to not be based on "valueChanges" and simplify things by adding a custom validator directly in the async validators array of the FormControl as explained below:

```
this.issueSubject = fb.control('', [Validators.required], [
    //Adding here something like OrderFormComponent.checkAsyncValue
]]);
```

Please note I would like to keep the usage of the following:

```
debounceTime(500).distinctUntilChanged()
```

**Is there a way to do it or is there mandatory to be based on valueChanges Observable?**

**EDIT**: *Something to add, one important drawback with my example is that the 'pending' property of the form won't be set while doing the custom asynchronous validation*

Thank you in advance

Comment: You might find this issue useful/interesting: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9119

Comment: you write your own validator, is your concern that it will be applied on each change instead of each 500 ms?

Comment: @cartant Well, so from what I understand it's not possible to achieve it the way I'm looking for because validators are not implemented as Observable objects in Angular

Comment: @Maximus Not only, I know we can do the same with promises and timeouts, but Observable has so many useful handlers it would be great to be able to use

Comment: an async validator can return an observable as well, not only promise

Comment: @maximus That is what the static method checkAsyncValue of my example do, but, in this case how to make use of debounceTime(500).distinctUntilChanged() without observing manually issueSubject.valueChanges? could you provide an example?

Comment: what is the reason for using `debounceTime(500).distinctUntilChanged()` in your case for this particular control?

Comment: @Maximus The reason is to avoid asking server too frequently or for the same value 2 times. The call to server is emulated by a timeout in my example. I know there are way to do it without Observable but this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919011/how-to-add-debounce-time-to-an-async-validator-in-angular-2) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6895)

Comment: @Maximus Thanks for the links, happy to see a lot of people facing the same situation. I see different implementations that could potentially work but one thing seems to be sure: that's not as simple as I expected it to be. Quite surprising (and disappointing) that Angular2 (inside which RxJS paradigm occupies a central place) hasn't made things more natural with Observables

Comment: it's not about observables, it's how form control <-> native input integration takes place

Comment: @Maximus 
 
I may be wrong but if FormControl's were automatically registering Observable validators on valueChanges then the problem would be solved. I mean for example: fb.control('', [], [ObsValidator1, ObsValidator2]]) Then the framework would have to do something like : formControl.getObservableValidators().forEach(observer){ formControl.valueChanges.switchMap( (control) => observer(control)); }