# Angular 4 Validator with an http observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an input component that on keyup I want to delay with a debounce and then fire off an http request which works

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { KeywordsApiService } from '../keywords-api.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Component({
  selector: 'input-group',
  templateUrl: './input-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-group.component.scss']
})
export class InputGroupComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() data: any;
  valid: boolean;
  invalidName: boolean;
  complexForm: FormGroup;
  pattern: RegExp;

  @Output() clicked: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() keyedup: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private keywordsApiService: KeywordsApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data);

    this.complexForm = this.fb.group({
      input: ['', Validators.pattern(this.data.pattern), this.invalidName]
    });
    console.log(this.complexForm.controls['input']);

    this.complexForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe(x => console.log(x));

    this.complexForm.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(500)
      .switchMap(val => this.keywordsApiService.getGroups())
      .subscribe(data => {
          this.invalidName = data.some(item => {
            return item == this.data.value
          });
          console.log(this.invalidName);
        });

  }

  click() {
    console.log(this.data.value);
    this.clicked.emit(true);
  }

  onKey() {
  }
}
```

I have a pattern validator on the input but I want to also check whether `this.validName` is true or false and use this in the validators.

I have updated the code above.

If `return item == this.data.value` returns `true` then I want to get `this.complexForm` to say `input` is not valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add debounce time to an async validator in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919011/how-to-add-debounce-time-to-an-async-validator-in-angular-2)

Comment: **I want to delay with a debounce and then fire off an http request which works** It works or not works? Or what is the question? :)

Comment: @AJT_82 ok well the request for this.keywordsApiService.getGroups() fires and console.log(this.validName); states true or false but if its true I want the validator to fail the validation

Comment: Have updated the code

Comment: So basically you want an additional validator? :)

Comment: @AJT_82 yeah! I think I might have got it actually

Comment: Oh okay, if it doesn't work out, let me know, I have an idea in my head on how to possibly solve this :)

Comment: And of course if you solve it, please post answer, I'm curious to see your solution :)

Comment: @AJT_82 posted the answer 

Comment: Not really looking at else code :P Okay, well if the code in your question, I would have just added a couple of lines of code and based on the boolean set a error on the form itself, or remove it. Don't know if it's suitable. But I don't see why not though if you want to set a error in your form if `this.invalidName` is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my code around quite a bit, I didn't need to do an http request on each type so I moved that to the parent component and passed the results down to this component with one-way binding.

it seems all I was missing was wrapping my 2 validators in `Validators.compose([])`

I also needed to changed the `segmentValidator` to compare the array of segments to see if the `control.value` of `'input'` matches which is done in the manner below.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Component({
  selector: 'input-group',
  templateUrl: './input-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-group.component.scss']
})
export class InputGroupComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() data: any;
  @Input() segments: any[];
  valid: boolean;
  invalidName: boolean;
  complexForm: FormGroup;
  pattern: RegExp;

  @Output() clicked: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() keyedup: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  segmentValidator(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    const input = control.value;
    if (this.segments) {
      return this.segments.includes(input) ? { nomatch: true } : null;
    }

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data);

    this.complexForm = this.fb.group({
      'input': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.pattern(this.data.pattern), this.segmentValidator.bind(this)])]
    });

    console.log(this.complexForm.controls['input']);

    this.complexForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe(x => x);

    this.complexForm.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(500)
      .subscribe(data => {
          this.keyedup.emit(this.data.value);
      });

  }

  click() {
    console.log(this.data.value);
    this.clicked.emit(true);
  }

  onKey() {
  }
}
```