# Debounce async Validator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-validation

I have a working async validator that does an HTTP request to the server to check if a username is already taken.
As I don't want to call the API after each keystroke I need to debounce the input stream.

I first had `throttleTime` in the service, but another topic on SO said this has to be on the one who subscribes, but no luck yet!

My Component:

```
this.form = this._fb.group(
      {
        username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50), NoWhitespaceValidator], [IsUserIdFreeValidator.createValidator(this._managementService)]]
      });
```

My Validator:

```
export class IsUserIdFreeValidator {
  static createValidator(_managementService: ManagementService) {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      return _managementService.isUserIdFree(control.value)
        .pipe(
          throttleTime(5000),
          (map(
            (result: boolean) => result === false ? { isUserIdFree: true } : null))
        );
    };
  }
}
```

My Service:

```
  public isUserIdFree(userId: string): Observable<{} | boolean | HttpError> {
    const updateUserCheck: UpdateUserCheck = new UpdateUserCheck();
    updateUserCheck.userID = userId;

    return this._httpClient.post<boolean>('UserManagementUser/IsUserIdFree', updateUserCheck));
  }
```

Comment: I think you need debounce, not throttle

Comment: Read this blog post, it's exactly what you're looking for https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

Comment: @ritaj I tried that and I also tried using delay

Comment: That's because you don't debounce on the HTTP call, but on the input value change. Are you using reactive forms, or template driven ?

Comment: @trichetriche I updated the code, I'm using reactive forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add debounce time to an async validator in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919011/how-to-add-debounce-time-to-an-async-validator-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this trough another way, via a propery called '[updateOn](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#note-on-performance)' on the control.

With template-driven forms:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
```

With reactive forms:

```
new FormControl('', {updateOn: 'blur'});
```

If you use the form-builder, since Angular 7 you can use [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/24599):

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
  email: ['', [CustomValidators.email], null, 'blur'],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
  static createValidator(_managementService: ManagementService) {
    const subject = new BehaviorSubject('');
    const observable = subject.asObservable().pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        switchMap(val => _managementService.isUserIdFree(val)),
        map((isUserIdFree: boolean) => isUserIdFree ?  null : { userIdTaken : true }),
        ); 
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      subject.next(control.value);
      return observable.pipe(takeUntil(timer(5000))); // acts as a way to make observable finite
    }
  }
```

The debouncing should happen on the value emitted by the control as opposed to the result returned from the http service. We start by emitting the value on an observable stream and piping it through `distinctUntilChanged`, which ensures that only a distinct value compared to the last emitted value gets past that stage of the pipe line. `debounceTime(x)` ensures only the last value after an 'x' amount of milliseconds emits.

The `switchMap` operator takes the control value and fires a get request to the backend and passes the new observable to the next stage of the pipeline. Finally, I have applied your existing map operator on the result from the backend to generate an appropriate error message.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, the `createValidator` method will be evaluated on every key stroke, which will result in single finite streams being created every time. This wont produce the desired result

Comment: No `createValidator` is factory method that captures the service in a closure and creates a function using it. This function will be invoked every time validation is run so yeah this will not work, there is a simple way with `setTimeout` but im going to cook something up with observables

Comment: @Jota.Toledo how about this one, it's the same stream going through the same pipe over multiple calls, so should be good. It also preserves state between requests.

Comment: Nah this is still not finite

Answer (score 1):

To anyone finding this question and set of answers, IMHO, this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919011/how-to-add-debounce-time-to-an-async-validator-in-angular-2/45007974#45007974). I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45007974/314114) is the correct one, unless you like Promises. I intend to post an answer there with a newer take (Angular 9+) solution.

EDIT: [here's my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919011/how-to-add-debounce-time-to-an-async-validator-in-angular-2/62662296#62662296) for how to do this.

Incidentally, before coming across this question and the other one I tried all three of the answers listed here. You can get them all to work, but the answer I linked to is far and away the most elegant. It's hard to figure out because it relies on behavior buried in the Angular framework that really ought to be in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Using observables, I did:

```
form = this._fb.group({
email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email], [this.validateEmailNotTaken.bind(this)]]
})

private _emailCancel$ = new Subject<void>();
 validateEmailNotTaken(control: AbstractControl): Observable<object> {
        this._emailCancel$.next();
        return race(
            timer(3000).pipe(map(_ => true)),
            this._emailCancel$.pipe(
                map(_ => false)
            )
        ).pipe(
            take(1),
            filter(val => !!val),
            switchMap(() => this.isEmailTaken(control.value).pipe(
                map(res => res ? {isTaken: true } : null)
            ))
        );
    }
```