# Debounce an Angular 4+ AsyncValidator (using RxJS 6)

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have been trying to interpret this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919011/how-to-add-debounce-time-to-an-async-validator-in-angular-2) but with newer RxJS the needed syntax has changed. There is something I don't get. My working `AsyncValidator`'s `validate` method looks like this:

```
  validate(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return Observable.create(resolve => {
      const pathname = control.value;
      if (!pathname || pathname.length < 1) { resolve(null);  return; }
      this.client.pathCheck(this.parentPath + '/' + pathname).subscribe(
        resp => resolve.next(resp.inuse ? { pathInUse: true } : null),
        err => resolve.next(null),
        () => resolve.complete(null)
      );
    });
  }
```

What I don't understand is how to fit in the `timer`, `pipe`, and `switchMap` functions to replace the `Observable.create`.

What I also don't understand is why the `debounce` pipe isn't used for this.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: there is an answer using debounceTime, I would definitely do it using debouncetime. It makes no sense also to wrap all code in an new observable. So I would definitely suggest the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57009006/6294072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it should be done with RxJS 6 - Using `timer`, `pipe` and `switchMap`

```
validate(control: AbstractControl): Promise < ValidationErrors | null > | Observable < ValidationErrors | null > {
    return timer(1000).pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
            const pathname = control.value;
            if (!pathname || pathname.length < 1) {
                return of(null);
            }
            return this.client.pathCheck(this.parentPath + '/' + pathname).pipe(
                map((res) => {
                    return resp.inuse ? { pathInUse: true } : null;
                })
            )
        })
    )
}
```

Bear in mind that Validators return either null if the FormControl is valid or an error object if it’s not. It seems that you are doing the opposite in your approach. Example:

```
if (!pathname || pathname.length < 1) {
    return of(null);
}
```

This will set the FormControl as valid. You might want to change that to something like this:

```
if (!pathname || pathname.length < 1) {
    return of({emptyPath: true});
}
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-euq6vt?)

Comment: thanks for this answer.   I do have one outstanding question:  When a second call to `validate` comes in and a new Observable is generated, what happens to the old one that is still waiting for `timer` to be expired?  Looking at the result it seems to get cancelled but I don't understand how.