# Debounce time not working when subscribing to the observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to send passwordAvailable request to server after sometime (3seconds) when the user starts typing.
But it gets sent anyways.
I have set debounceTime to 3 seconds, still nothing.
This is my validator

```
validate = (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> | null => {
        const value = control.value;

        return this.authService.passwordAvailable(value, this._username).pipe(
            debounceTime(3000),
            tap(
                ()=>console.log('hi')
            ),
            map(value => {        
            if (value == 'true') {
                return null;
            }

            return { matchNotFound: true };
            })
            
        );
    }
```

My Component.ts

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private passwordValidators: PasswordValidators,
    ) {}

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.passwordValidators.setUsername(this.username);

    this.changePassForm = this.fb.group({
      oldPassword : [this.password, 
        Validators.required, 
        this.passwordValidators.validate
      ]
    });
    
  }
```

My Service

```
passwordAvailable(password: string, username: string): Observable<any>{
    let data = {password: password, username: username};
    return this.http.get<any>('url:check-password',{params: data});
  }
```

the service returns string as (true or false)

Please Help, thanks in advance

I even tried, using valueChanges, but service isnt even getting called here, this is what i tried

```
return control.valueChanges.pipe(
            debounceTime(3000),
            tap(()=>console.log('hi')),
            map((val) => {return this.authService.passwordAvailable(val, this._username)}),
            map((v: any) => {
                if (v == 'true') {
                    return null;
                }
    
                return { matchNotFound: true };
            })
        )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919011/how-to-add-debounce-time-to-an-async-validator-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to

```
return timer(3000).pipe(
            switchMap(() => {
                return this.authService.passwordAvailable(value, this._username).pipe(
                    tap(
                        ()=>console.log('hi')
                    ),
                    map(value => {        
                    if (value == 'true') {
                        return null;
                    }
        
                    return { matchNotFound: true };
                    })
                    
                );
            })
        )
```

Now api is getting hit after 3 seconds.

With DebounceTime, i tried changing it to

```
return control.valueChanges.pipe(
            debounceTime(2000),
            switchMap(value=>{
                return this.authService.passwordAvailable(value, this._username).pipe(
                    map(value => {        
                    if (value == 'true') {
                        return null;
                    }
        
                    return { matchNotFound: true };
                    })
                    
                );
            })
        )
```

But still no request sent, so timer was the only option left

Comment: The debounceTime should be before the call to the httpclient. Problem with the http call is, is that it is a so called cold observable. Every time you call it you get a new observable instead of a reusable one. That's why the answer in the other comment shows the debounceTime being piped before the http call.

Answer (score 0):

should be simply

```
this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      switchMap(value=>{
        return this.authService.passwordAvailable(value, this._username)
      })
      ).subscribe(res=>{console.log(res)})
```

That's. you observer the control changes, but only emit a value if pass 300 miliseconds -debounceTime(300)-. But you don't want the result of change, you want return the value of the service.passwordAvailable -switchMap-

Comment: I tried it and  edited my own answer, but it still doesn't works, no request sent (unsubscribes)

Comment: remember you need create the subscription **after** you create the FormControl -if you has a FormGroup after create the formGroup and use `this.myForm.get('search').valueChanges.pipe(...)`