# Angular 2 - ES6 - trigger form validator depending on checkbox value

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular2-forms

What i'm trying to achieve is explained in [How to trigger Form Validators in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260082/how-to-trigger-form-validators-in-angular2)

But in that, there's no explanation about how do you pass the checkbox state into the validator for the text box. My code is as follows

**The Component:**

```
export class FormComponent { 

  static get annotations() {
        return [
            new Component ({
                templateUrl: "./form.component.html",
                directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
            })
        ];
    }

    static get parameters() {
        return [[FormBuilder]];
    }

    constructor (formbuilder) {
        this.checkbox = new Control(false);
        this.name = new Control('', nameValidator(this.checkbox.value));

        this.myForm = formbuilder.group({
            checkbox: this.checkbox,
            name: this.name,
        });

        this.checkbox.valueChanges
        .subscribe({
            next: (value) => { this.name.updateValueAndValidity(); }
        });
    }
}
```

**The Validator function**

```
function nameValidator(checkbox) {
    return function(control) {
        if (checkbox && !control.value)
            return { required: true };
        return null;
    }
}
```

But the updated checkbox value is not reflected in the validator function on calling `updateValueAndValidity()`. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the content of the content of the shouldCreateNewTeam method? I think the problem is when calling it in the form builder... Thanks!

Comment: Updated. Renamed my variables while posting here. Missed this somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you don't subscribe the right way for checkbox updates from the associated control. You need to provide a callback to be notified when the checkbox is updated:

```
this.checkbox.valueChanges
    .subscribe(
      (value) => { this.name.updateValueAndValidity(); }
    );
```

Regarding the value of the checkbox, you provide it as value (it's a primitive type not a reference) so Angular2 can't update it. To have access to the current value, you need to provide the control itself (reference) and use its value property:

```
function nameValidator(checkboxCtrl) {
  return function(control) {
    let checkbox = checkboxCtrl.value;
      if (checkbox && !control.value)
          return { required: true };
      return null;
  }
}
```

Here is the new way to create the controls:

```
this.checkbox = new Control(false);
this.name = new Control('', nameValidator(this.checkbox));
```

Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/bA3Y3G4oAk9wanzNMiS2?p=preview.