# How to trigger Form Validators in angular2?

Tags: angular

I have created angular2 web application .in that i  have implemented a custom  validator with form builder it will  work on submit but i need to trigger validation dynamically in other form control value change please any one give suggestion to achieve this

thank you

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger Form Validators in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260082/how-to-trigger-form-validators-in-angular2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
  this.RegisterForm1.controls["form control name"].updateValueAndValidity();
```

i think may  be help you

Comment: where i add this

Comment: in your ionchange function

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of form with custom validation

```
formInitilization() {
      this.loginForm = this._fb.group({
        email: ['', [Validators.required ,this.emailValidation]]
      });
  }

  emailValidation(control?:FormControl){ 
  let val=control.value.trim();
  let emailp:any=/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
      if(!emailp.test(val))
          return {    isInvalidEmail:true };
      return null;
  }

<input type="text" formControlName="email" autofocus='true'>
<span *ngIf='!loginForm.controls["email"].valid && loginForm.controls["email"].dirty' > 
  Error message
</span>
```