# Prevent Submitting Form after Validation in Angular 5

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular5

I have the following code for demo purposes, showing a simple form row with error messages and a submit button:

```html
<form [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
   <tid-form-row>
      <label tid-ui-label for="temperatureInput">Temperature:</label>
      <input [tid-ui-input]="{required: true}" id="temperatureInput" name="temperatureName" placeholder="20,4"
             [(ngModel)]="temperatureModel" #temperature="ngModel" [tidDigits]="{integer: 2, fraction: 1}" required>
      <ng-template #hint>
         <small tid-ui-hint>The yellow color indicates that this field is required.</small>
      </ng-template>
      <div tid-ui-error *ngIf="temperature.invalid && (temperature.dirty || temperature.touched); else hint">
         <span *ngIf="temperature?.errors.required">Field is required.</span>
         <span *ngIf="temperature?.errors.tidDigits">Must be max 2 integer digits and max 1 fraction digit.</span>
      </div>
   </tid-form-row>
   <tid-button type="submit">Check validation</tid-button>
</form>
```

where `tidDigits` is a [custom ValidatorDirective](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) with this `ValidatorFactory`:

```
export function digitsValidator(config: any): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    const value = control.value;
    const errorObject: any = {tidDigits: {value: control.value}};
    let passed = true;

    if (value) {
      const [integer, fraction] = value.split(',');
      if (config.integer && config.integer >= 0) {
        if (integer.length > config.integer) {
          passed = false;
          errorObject.tidDigits.integer = integer.length;
        }
      }
      if (config && config.fraction && config.fraction >= 0) {
        if (fraction.length > config.fraction) {
          passed = false;
          errorObject.tidDigits.fraction = fraction.length;
        }
      }
    }
    return passed ? null : errorObject;
  };
}
```

I want the demo to show the different error messages when the user clicks the submit button. For this is a demo form, I do not want the form to submit at all.

The error messages show up correctly (after pressing the submit button) when the field is empty (`required`-Validator) or e.g. 20,44 is entered (`tidDigits`-Validator). However, if a valid value is entered (e.g. 20,4), the form submits - i.e. the page is reloaded and the field name is appended to the URL: `/tid-form-row?temperatureName=20,4`

**Is there any way to prevent a form from submitting at all?**

I tried `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"` with `onSubmit() { return false; }` and also `(ngSubmit)="$event.preventDefault()"` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909585/angular-2-how-to-prevent-a-form-from-submitting-on-keypress-enter), but it did not work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The default value of the type attribute in a `<button>` tag is `submit`, if you want to prevent that, you need to overwrite this with:

```html
<button type="button"></button>
```

Removing `type="submit"` won't suffice, more details here: [HTML button to NOT submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825856/html-button-to-not-submit-form)

---

If you want to validate anyway, maybe you could try the following:

```html
<form #form>
    <button type="button" (click)="validateForm(form)"></button>
</form>
```

And, in your Typescript code:

```js
public validateForm(form: NgForm) {
  for (const control in form.controls) {
    control.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```

Comment: It does indeed not submit, when I change the type - but it also won't validate the input anymore.

Comment: Try yo add `(click)="yourValidateFunction()"`?

Comment: Tried it with `<form #form ...
 <button (click)="form.controls['temperatureName'].updateValueAndValidity()" ...` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43384221/2725515)) but it still doesn't validate. Console log: `Cannot read property 'temperatureName' of undefined` Any other thoughts?

Comment: The validation procedure is triggered upon form validation, if you want to validate without submitting, you'll have to 1) disable submitting (my answer) and 2) trigger the form validation manually. I'm looking for point 2 right now.

Comment: Maybe you can try the heavy weaponery: `form.controls.foreach(c => c.updateValueAndValidity())`. Does that work? That will indicate wether or not we're on the right track.

Comment: The arrow notation does not work in HTML-Tags' (click) ("Error: unexpected token '>'"). Also I cannot refer to `form` inside the class, because the reference `#form` is only valid in the template... Tried `ViewChild(form) form;` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Why not calling a wrapping function with your form as a parameter?

Comment: @fronteyes I edited the post with what I meant, please check it out.

Comment: "Cannot read property 'foreach' of undefined"... I think I'll switch to reactive forms :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: This answer didn't work for me, there is no `foreach` on [controls](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#controls). Using Angular 5.2.9 and template driven form.

Comment: @PimHazebroek controls has changed from array to object in a recent Angular update. That shouldn't be so hard to loop on that object properties though...

Comment: @Adrien Do you know which version particularly by any chance?

Comment: @PimHazebroek no idea. I updated the answer to take into account your observations.

Comment: Thanks @AdrienBrunelat

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `type="submit"` on the button.

If you have `(ngOnSubmit)` defined on your `form` element, any `submit` button will activate that function. I typically just use the `(click)` event listener on buttons within forms to activate functions.

Is there a reason you are bypassing the validation on input changes? Unfortunately you are listening for `submit`. So you may have to backtrack a little and re-engineer the solution. You could run the `updateValueAndValidity` on your form controls when the button has a `(click)` event. For most of this to work, you may need to use a Reactive Form instead of a Template Driven Form though.

Check out [AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl)

Comment: "submit" is the default button type in a form, isn't it? It is a customer requirement to validate the input fields not on blur or changes but on submit.

The problem here is, that I need the "submit" action for Angular to validate the form - but I want to prevent the form from being submitted, also if the validation succeeds.

Switching to Reactive Forms is possible, but would be some kind of effort.

Comment: If I were you I'd switch to reactive forms. And setup your `(ngOnSubmit)` function to run the `updateValueAndValidity()` function on the form controls. I think you might be hitting your head on the ceiling with the template driven approach.