# ANGULAR TESTING - Form Input type="number" should only accept numbers

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-reactive-forms

i am trying to write some unit tests for my project and I needed some help about it.
I have an input and i want to verify that it accepts only numbers/digits, otherwise it should be invalid.

TS:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        inputNumber: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]]});
```

HTML Template:

```
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput placeholder="pls give a number" type="number" step="1" formControlName="inputNumber">
</mat-form-field>
```

Unit Test (*.spec.ts):

```
it('FormControl only accepts numbers', () => {
        let inputNumber = component.form.controls['inputNumber'];
        inputNumber.setValue(null);
        console.log('Valid :', inputNumber.valid);//valid: false (required)

        inputNumber.setValue('any string or !number');
        expect(inputNumber.valid).toBe(false);//but returns TRUE
});
```

thanks !

Comment: Your problem is that even though you updated the value, it doesn't automatically trigger the html form validators to check again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260082/does-anybody-know-how-to-trigger-form-validators-in-angular2

Comment: [update] Even if we call updateValueAndValidity(), I have the same result.

Comment: The `FormControl` is not aware of element attributes like `type`. You need a validator if you want the control to know that non-numeric input is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem, which is that formControl does not even distinguish between number and/or any other field.

Ended up creating my own Control

```
export class NumberControl extends FormControl {
    _value: number | undefined;
    get value() {
      return this._value;
    }

    set value(value) {
      this._value = (value || value === 0) ? Number(value) : undefined;
    }
  }
```

which than can be used like

```
 formControl = new NumberControl('', field.validator);
```

That way you can make sure you either get a number or undefined.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add pattern validation  `Validators.pattern(/\d/)`

> Like this

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        inputNumber: [null, [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/\d/), Validators.min(0)]]});
```

because angular reactive form doesn't consider html validation in all cases